# Transferring files from windows to linux box with pscp

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty, pscp

I am trying to transfer a directory to a linux box I have set up.  I use putty to ssh in and the prompt is open and working.

I am trying to get a directory from my host computer(windows) on to the linux box which is open through putty.

I have tried many threads on here but none are solving my problem so thought I would ask for new attention.

I Opened a command prompt on my windows computer and typed the following command:

```
pscp C:\Users\user\projects\Locust_Automation rbed2-user@ip-11-34-12-45:~/Dir
```

*I changed names of things to protect info*

This is giving me the error:

```
ssh_init: Host does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

To be very clear what I am trying to do:  I want to get a directory off my windows computer onto a Linux box that I am connected to through putty.

Comment: If this is a one off just fire up a ftp server on the Linux box for sufficient time to transfer the data

Comment: @EdHeal what are you talking about?

Comment: Just get the Linux box to run a ftp server. Use ftp to transfer. Kill ftp server

Comment: Try more basic things first. Can you ping the IP? Can you use PuTTY SSH to connect to it? "Host does not exist" is a pretty clear error message really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your pc does not know what host ip-11-34-12-45 is.
is it possible this is just the alias you named the host in putty?

maybe try entering the ip directly in pscp instead of this alias:

educated guess:

```
pscp C:\Users\user\projects\Locust_Automation rbed2-user@11.34.12.45:/home/file
```

Comment: This did not work sadly.  And no this is the name of the prompt from putty.  That isnt the exact ip, but I am using the ip that links the box